# Extracting random effect using ranef() in brms package

Tags: r, list, brms

I am managing the result of random effects using ranef() in brms packages.

```
bmodel<- brm(pop ~  RDB2000pop + Temperature2003 + Population2003 + 
                     (1+RDB2000pop+Temperature2003+Population2003 |species_id),
                   data      = dfpop_chenv,
                   family    = cumulative(link = "logit", threshold = "flexible"),
                   prior   = c(set_prior("normal(0,10)", class = "b")), 
                   warmup    = 1000,
                   iter      = 10000,
                   chains    = 4,
                   save_all_pars = TRUE) 

ranef(bmodel)[[1]]
```

[image]

I would like to extract the result of "Population2003".

```
ranef(bmodel)$Population2003
NULL
```

How do I extract the result of a specific variable in the model?

Comment: It looks like a tridimensional array. What about `ranef(bmodel)[[1]][, , "Population2003"]`?